# Jest/Vue: registering components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-component, yarnpkg

Why can't I mount my component in my Jest spec (most code here is omitted for brevity)?

```
# Photos.vue
<script>
  import Vue from 'vue'

  export default {
    name: 'photos'
    data: function () {
      ...
    }
  }
</script>
```

Here's my spec:

```
# Photos.test.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'

Vue.component('photos', require('./Photos.vue').default)

describe('photos', () => {
  test('is a Vue instance', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(photos)
    expect(wrapper.isVueInstance()).toBeTruthy()
  })
})
```

Here's the error:

```
ReferenceError: photos is not defined

   6 | describe('photos', () => {
   7 |   test('is a Vue instance', () => {
>  8 |     const wrapper = mount(photos)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use photo because you didn't define it.

```
# Photos.test.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'

let photos = require('./Photos.vue')
Vue.component('photos', photos)

describe('photos', () => {
  test('is a Vue instance', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(photos)
    expect(wrapper.isVueInstance()).toBeTruthy()
  })
})
```

Comment: Ah, thank-you. I thought the `name: 'photos'` property in the component made the name available?

Comment: @CD-RUM In practice, the only application of using `name` is for self-referencing components. It's good practice to put it but most of the time you don't need it.

Comment: Makes _total sense_. Thanks for the info!